# Exporting .props files in project template VS2012/13

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2012, export, wizard

I am attempting to export a project as a template. There are two .props files (one for Win32 configuration and the other for x64 configuration.

When I run the export wizard, a zip is created WITHOUT the .prop files included. However, the .vcxproj file still references the .props files and and error occurs when a project is created using the exported template.

How can I export the .props files with the rest of the code and apply correctly to any new project using the template? Preferably, without using a custom wizard.

The error that appears when trying to create a project with the template:

==================================================

Unable to read the project file "Window2.vcxproj".

c:\Users\Steve\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Window2\Window2\Window2.vcxproj(51,5): The imported project "c:\Users\Steve\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Window2\Window2\Configuration Win32.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

==================================================

Thanks for any help in advance,

Steve