# Visual Studio 2013 export Property Sheets to Template

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates

I am Creating a C++ Project template and using the export template wizard to do it.
I had added a custom property sheet to my template project (the one which am going to export)

on successfully exporting my project template I created a new project using the template, but the project fails to load saying that it can't find the property sheet (it mentions the project directory path and says no such file exists).

I know the same question has been asked before : [Exporting .props files in project template VS2012/13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597561/exporting-props-files-in-project-template-vs2012-13)
But it has no answer for a year

I even tried including the property sheet as part of the project before exporting. still the same error

Please Help!

Edit:

I even tried manually putting the .props file into the zip archive it still shows the same error.
I think the new project gets loaded before the .props file gets added to the new project directory.

Note : Manually putting the .props file into the new project directory and then reloading the project works. but I don't want to copy paste it every time I create a new project from the template.

Comment: It forgets to put the .props file into the .zip archive, take care of it yourself.

Comment: I know and I did that too even after that it shows the same error. I think the project gets loaded before the the .props file gets added to the new project directory

Comment: If you haven't solved this out yet, see my answer here [How to include a property sheet in VC project template](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42824833/5199222)