# Visual Studio removes props file definition from vcxproj file

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, vsprops

I created a Project Template https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/creating-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2017
Inside vcxproj I have props file definition:
 (left side of the image): 
[props in vcxproj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUq6s.png)

The prop file is present in the project package.
When creating a New Project the line with prop file definition is deleted from vcxproj by Visual Studio.
When I restored it manually and reload project everything works fine. 
What can be the reason Visual Studio is doing that?

Comment: Not sure the reason why Visual Studio delete the props file in the project file, I have given a answer below, you can check if it helps, if not, please let me how did you get that issue, share me some steps to reproduce this issue, I will keep follow up.

Comment: Thx for a response. I made the simplest solution and added there  a props file. It's here: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hb18499lsg1dqr6/ConsoleApplication6.zip?dl=0) Then exported it as template and tried to create a new project based on it. VS is issuing an error: 

'Unable to read the project file "ConsoleApplication63.vcxproj".
The imported project "c:\Users\tkot\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication63\ConsoleApplication63\PropertySheet.props" was not found... 

All needed files are in Documents\Visual Studio 2015\My Exported Templates\ConsoleApplication6.

Comment: yes, if you are using VS 2015, you would get that error. You can upgrade your VS to 2017, if you do not want upgrade VS, please check my update answer for some more details.

Answer (score 1):

> Visual Studio removes props file definition from vcxproj file

First, make sure the props file exists in the project template, Second, make sure the new project is created with the custom template. You can follow below steps:

1. Create a new C++ project, which I named it `MyCustomTemplate`.
2. Unload the project , then add `<Import Project="$projectname$.props"` /> to the project file `.vcxproj`.
3. Reload the project, go to the Project tab, select Export Template, click Next and Finish. (You can check if the props line is exists in your template file, open the `.vcxproj` with notepad.)
4. Create new project with the new custom template **MyCustomTemplate**, then unload the project and check the props file.

[image]

**Update:**

Since you are using the Visual Studio 2015, you would get that error. And if you upgrade your Visual Studio to 2017, everything will be fine.

If you do not want to upgrade your Visual Studio to 2017, you can follow the method of Paul H. to resolve this issue:

[How to include a property sheet in VC project template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37744478/how-to-include-a-property-sheet-in-vc-project-template/42824833#42824833)

Hope this helps.