# Export Project Template with props files VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

i have try exporting a project template in Visual Studio, my project do have few props file.

the zip file does not zip the props files and whenever I new a project using the template, it show unable to import the props file.

There are similar issue here since VS2012 but it seems like nobody can resolve?
[Exporting .props files in project template VS2012/13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597561/exporting-props-files-in-project-template-vs2012-13#)

I will need to export project template with the props files, is that any work around? Otherwise the point of exporting template will become meaningless

Currently i am exporting a project template without props file, and able to new a project with the exported template, but i have to manually add the existing props file